# Derivation of Sampling 2d Tent Distribution

Tags: sampling, importance-sampling

I am trying to do the derivation of transforming uniformly distributed 2D points on the unit square into the 2D "tent" distribution below. i.e the standard method of getting the cdf and inversting it.

[image]

Peter Shirley has the sampling code for tent funciton in [his book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=knpN6mnhJ8QC&pg=PA56&lpg=PA56&dq=importance%20sampling%20of%20triangle%20tent%20function&source=bl&ots=OLbIq51B9B&sig=ACfU3U17KRJrkwjvmEmZA3elroPGDmkTwQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiou6yJ5In4AhVFoVwKHRExAI4Q6AF6BAgsEAM#v=onepage&q=importance%20sampling%20of%20triangle%20tent%20function&f=false) Realistic Ray tracing as this:

[image]

And I am trying to do the derivation of the formula here but somewhere I am making a mistake:

So for the first part t=[-1,0), the cdf is:

[image]

But I don't know where I got it wrong. Any idea anyone? Thank you.

Comment: You forgot the first part in the second expression: $P(t) = \int_{-1}^{t}(1-|\tau|)\,d\tau = \frac{1}{2} + \int_{0}^t(1-\tau)\,d\tau$. I haven't checked whether you have made other mistakes.

Comment: pretty sure the second expression is t to 1 but it works out either way

Comment: @pmw1234 It isn't.